# How data movement from large register to small register works in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, register

I went through a VHDL sample code for memory management. In that data from a 32 bit register was directly moved into a 8 bit register. My doubt it is how this data movement can happen? Is there is any default condition for VHDL for such data transfer?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. In general, VHDL is not big on things happening by "default conditions" and very big on stating exactly what you want to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is to match up the bit indices, so if you have

```
signal reg32 : bit_vector(31 downto 0);
signal reg8 : bit_vector(7 downto 0);

reg8 <= reg32;
```

it is equivalanet to

```
reg8(7 downto 0) <= reg32(7 downto 0);
```

However, any decent VHDL compiler should give you at least a warning about the width mismatch.

Comment: IIRC, assignments between slices of different sizes are not legal, so the code would be in error (not simply a warning). Also, I believe the correct behavior would be for the VHDL tool to *ignore* the indices, and make the assignments between elements in left-to-right order. Would you confirm it?